# C# Platform Collisions Not Working With Multiple Platforms

Tags: c#, game-physics, collision

Right now I'm trying to make a simple game editor in C#, however there's a problem with when the user adds more than one platform to the screen:

```
private void tmrRunGame_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Platform plat in platList)
            {
                if (plat.getBounds().IntersectsWith(player.getBounds()))
                {
                    tmrGravity.Stop();
                    isColliding = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isColliding = false; 
                }
            }

            if(player.getY() < 500 && !isJumping && !isColliding)
            {
                tmrGravity.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                tmrGravity.Stop();
            }
        }
```

This code only stops the user from falling through the last created platform, all of the ones before that the user is able to just fall right through. What makes this all the more confusing is that the program is detecting collisions for all of the platforms, but only doing what it's supposed to for one! It's very frustrating and any help is appreciated.

This is how I'm adding platforms if that helps in any way:

```
private void pbPlatformSelect_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Platform plat = new Platform(100, 10, 50, 50);
            plat.drawTo(this);
            platList.Add(plat);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `foreach` loop with this code:

```
var playerBounds = player.GetBounds ();
isColliding = platList.Any (plat => plat.GetBounds ().IntersectsWith (playerBounds);
if (isColliding) tmrGravity.Stop ();
```

if you don't like LINQ, you can change you loop like this:

```
var playerBounds = player.GetBounds ();
isColliding = false;
foreach (var plat in platList) {
    if (plat.GetBounds ().IntersectsWith (playerBounds)) {
        isColliding = true;
        tmrGravity.Stop ();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to break out of the foreach loop once you determine you have collided with something.  If you have 3 platforms, and you collide with the first, isColliding is true, but if it doesn't collide with the second platform, it will switch isColliding to false.  In the end, whatever the intersection result of the last platform in the list is, is what isColliding's value will be.

So try putting 'break;' right after 'isColliding = true';

This is also an efficiency improvement because if you have 1,000 platforms and the player collides with the first one, we don't really care about the others (from what I can tell) and we save ourselves 999 iterations of the loop.